# Netbeans Tomcat - Cannot access WADL. Please restart your REST application

Tags: web-services, jersey, tomcat9, netbeans-8.2

Im using netbeans and the application is deployed in tomcat localhost:8080.

But when I try to test the web services, I'm getting the following error message.

[image]

[image]

Webpage is opening in localhost:8080 as well. Please find the screenshot below.

[image]

Application Config file is updated as below,

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public ApplicationConfig() {

register(com.test.serverdetails.camrnvcenter.ServerInventoryRestful.class);
    register(com.dso.selfhealing.vmreset.VmController.class);
    register(com.dso.initiative.InitiativeController.class);
}
```

Comment: Why are there two slashes on the URL after 8080 in the error message? There should only be one.

Comment: Context path is "/" so its double slash. I have changed the path and tested it as well. Still showing the same error